# AudioManager.getProperty API android version

Tags: android, audio, version

I have project Audio based Device-2-Device communication , I think I need this
AudioManager.getProperty API library to make it work , my question : what android version support this API ( AudioManager.getProperty API) ? ,also if there is some any resource can help me with, I will be thankful.

Answer (score 0):

You need minimum API 17 (Jelly Bean mr1)